# Remove navigator.connection.rtt from flutter WebView widget

Tags: android, flutter, dart, webview

I'm using a flutter package [(InAppWebView v6)](https://inappwebview.dev/) which uses flutter WebView widget.

Everything works well, but when checking the browser's headless state, there's a field connection-rtt which is set to be 0.

[browser's headless state](https://infosimples.github.io/detect-headless)

I'm trying to remove this field or to change it, but it's a read-only variable (as described in [NetworkInformation interface definition](https://wicg.github.io/netinfo/#dom-networkinformation)) and that's probably why all my attemps are blocked.

I tried to change the field throug js code:

```
javascriptString = '''navigator.connection.rtt = undefine;''';

await controller.runJavascript(javascriptString);
```

Also tried with:

```
JavascriptString = '''navigator.connection.rtt = 100;''';
```

And I get the new value when running:

```
javascriptScript = '''return navigator.connection.rtt''';
const res = await controller.runJavascript(javascriptString);
```

But then when loading the test headless url I get

```
connection-rtt: 0
```

Am I doing something wrong? Or this is just the reault of trying to change read-only variables?

Is there any way I can change this value?

P.S.  I'm running it on emulator with android API 34.